# How to use cURL and mail in AWS Lambda

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, curl, lambda, aws-lambda

I run a Linux machine with 50+ hourly cron jobs of the format:

```
00 00 * * * /usr/bin/curl http://domain.com/page.php/reports | mail -s "domain.com report cron successful execution" email@otherdomain.com
```

The above cron:

1. sends the output of **curl** command to pipe
2. mail the output to **email@otherdomain.com** with subject line **"domain.com report cron successful execution"**

How can I set these cron to use with AWS Lambda, as I do not want a separate server just for these cron jobs.

If this is possible, I can setup AWS SES to work with this.

Comment: You can't just setup a cron job in a linux server and then somehow magically say "run on Lambda". You have to actually write an AWS Lambda function, and in that Lambda function it would probably make more sense to use the AWS SES SDK instead of issuing a `curl` command. Please do some research into what AWS Lambda is.

Comment: I know that I have to write a function. and the curl command generates the output to be sent via mail. Anyways, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For scheduling the CRON, you should use CloudWatch Events. You can set a CRON expression that will trigger the CloudWatch Event. This event can in turn [trigger a Lambda function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html).

Your Lambda function can make HTTP calls using the oh so great [`requests`](http://python-requests.org) package. Instructions for deployment on Lambda [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html). You can also use the not so easy to use [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) module as an alternative to `requests` if you don't want to package `requests` with your Lambda function.

As for sending emails, AWS SES would be the easiest avenue. You can alternatively use the [`email`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html) module, though I've never used it in the context of a Lambda function.

Comment: Thank you for the simple explanation and the insight on how to proceed forward.